# Livewire 3: Tabs and #Url Parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

A bit tricky mby, ive got a Livewire Component with multiple Tabs, each Tab holds a Child Component, one of this Child-component adds query params.

Maybe somebody has an idea how i can remove one of these query params from the child compoenent when a tab changes?

Comment: Please add more information, publish your code

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with events.

Assume that the tab change event is javascript only then you would do something like this

```
@script
<script>
   $wire.dispatch('clearQuery');
</script>
@endscript
```

If it done within a livewire component (the tab change) then add the event like this

```
public function tabChangeFunction()
{
    // function stuff
    $this->dispatch('clearQuery'); 
}
```

Now you need to listen on the componet you want to clear the query from

```
//include the attribute (assuming livewire 3)
use Livewire\Attributes\On; 

// this is in the livewire class as a function
#[On('clearQuery')] 
public function clearQuery()
{
    $this->query = null;
    // or something like this ^
}
```

Full documentation can be found here [Laravel Livewire 3 Events](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events)

Comment: I thought about smth like this in the first place too. But the issue is, that the child component that adds the query param, isnt renderen anymore when the tab changes. So it cant remove the param on a event anymore - it cant react in any event...

Comment: I havent found a way to remove a query param that isnt added by the component itself...

Comment: instead of removing the component from the DOM you should just hide it then it will still be there for you to manipulate.